# when build my project i got an error in builb.gradle file

Tags: android

I want to implement google analytics in my project and at the same time I used some google authentication dependencies when i run my project i got an error like this..... Please help me to find a solution on this issue---

here it is my build.gradle(app level)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':materialviewpager')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.0.5'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I got an error like this

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.2.1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/Office Project/RealMilk/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: you have to Install google's Repository.that will be use in your Project after Install

Comment: Make sure all the com.google.android.gms:play-services with one revision If you use 9.2.1 then change all to 9.2.1. And update latest play_service_library for SDK Manager

Comment: Show build.gradle at project version

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the `classpath` in project's main `build.gradle`.

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```

to this.